# catch response when send jsonp request phonegap

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cordova, jsonp

I write application by phonegap 
Server Side I write by nodejs

```
exports.login = function(request, response) {
    var keys = Object.keys(request.query);
    request.body= JSON.parse(keys[1]);
    Accounts.findOne({
        name : request.body.name
    }, function(err, docs) {
        if (!docs) {
            response.json('{"error": "user-not-found"}');
        } else {
            console.log("docs: ", docs);
            Accounts.validatePassword(request.body.password, docs['hashedPass'], docs['salt'], function(error, res) {
                if (error) {
                    response.json(error);
                }
                if (res) {
                    generateToken(request.body.name, request.body.device, function(res) {
                        if (res) {
                            response.json('{"token": "' + res + '"}');
                        } else {
                            response.json('{"error": "cant-create-token"}');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    response.json('{"error": "invalid-password"}');
                }
            });

        }
    })
}
```

Phonegap: I write function to login

```
function LoginUser(info)
{
    var varUrl=server+"/auth/login";
    $.ajax({
            url:varUrl,
            type:"GET",
            contentType:"application/json",
            headers: {
                            Accept:"application/json",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                        },              
            data:info,              
            dataType:"jsonp", 
            success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log("HERE");
                    console.log(data);                      
                },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }


    });
}
```

and I request it will like this `http://localhost:3000/auth/login?callback=jQuery161014894121675752103_1361459462241&{%22name%22:%22fdfdfd%22,%22password%22:%22fdfdfdfd%22}&_=1361459615743`

and when I see in the response of tab network of developer of chrome is `"{\"error\": \"user-not-found\"}"`

but I can not catch this repsonse in `function LoginUser(info)` above
How to get it because in console it print `error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }`

I dont know why.
Can you help me.

Comment: Why are you using GET request, you should use POST for login.

Comment: I have tried get and post and get the same problem above

Comment: jsonp is always a get request.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you have to use callback and in the response of your
jsonp file you need to do:

```
jQuery161014894121675752103_1361459462241({"error": "user-not-found"})
```

Where the function name comes from the callback variable in your jsonp request.
Cause a jsonp request just "include" a script tag in your site, which can execute js (basically).

Comment: I just try and get the sameproblem Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery161014894121675752103_1361459462241 is not defined  and it print in error: function(err){ console.log(err); }

Comment: You have to use the on the server side (assuming php):

    print $_REQUEST['callback']."({'error':'not logged in'})";

Comment: I use nodejs in server side

Comment: what you have to use as function is:
http://localhost:3000/auth/login?callback=jQuery161014894121675752103_1361459462241&{%22name%22:%22fdfdfd%22,%22password%22:%22fdfdfdfd%22}&_=1361459615743

the content of the variable ```callback``` on the server side.

Comment: request.body= JSON.parse(keys[1]);
It too many info and I just get name and password by doing above